# How can I configure the items shown on the Touch Bar Control Strip when the display is locked?

Tags: keyboard, high-sierra, touch-bar

I know I can configure the Touch Bar Control Strip in System Preferences, but how do I configure the items shown when the screen is locked?

In particular, I would like to configure it so that the previous/play-pause/next and mute/volume down/volume up keys remain in the same position regardless of whether the screen is locked or not.